# insert mysql foreign key value via form select option

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am currently in the process of making an insert page which should allow me to add data to my database. However I have been running into a problem recently.
My insert form contains a select that shows the data from the linked table of which I want the id inserted into the other table.

**example of how my database:**

```
---------------------------
| location_id | location  |
|-------------------------|
|      1      | Amsterdam |
|-------------------------|
|      2      | Hilversum |
|-------------------------|
|      3      | Loosdrecht|
|-------------------------|

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| product_id | productname | productcode | amount | product_location_id |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      1     |   Hammer    |    HK47     |   10   |          1          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      2     |    saw      |    ZW67     |   13   |          3          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

as you can see product_location_id is the foreign key that should tell which product is on what location by showing the primary key location_id from the first table.

**The code I used to try and make it happen:**

**Manager.php**

```
    class Manager {

       protected $conn;
    
       function __construct($conn) {
          $this->conn = $conn;
       }
    
      function createProducts() {
         $statement = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO supplies 
         (productname, productcode, amount, product_location_id) VALUES 
         (?,?,?,?)");
        
          $statement->bindValue(1, $_POST["productname"]);
          $statement->bindValue(2, $_POST["productcode"]);
          $statement->bindValue(3, $_POST["amount"]);
          $statement->bindValue(4, $_POST["product_location_id"]);
        
          $statement->execute();
        
       }
    
       function getLocations() {
          $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT location_id, location FROM 
          location");
        
          $statement->execute();
        
          return $statement;
       }
    }
```

**create.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'database.php';
    
    require ("../src/Classes/Manager.php");
    
    $productManager = new Manager($conn);
    
    $getLocatie = $productManager->getLocations();
    
    
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
            $addProduct = $productManager->createProducts();
            header("Location: read.php");
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
            header("Location: read.php");
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Create</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" class="formHandler">
            <label for="productname">Productname</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="productname" name="productname" placeholder="productname"/><p/>
            
            <label for="productcode">Productcode</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="productcode" name="productcode" placeholder="productcode"/><p/>
            
            <label for="aantal">Amount</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="amount"/><p/>
            
            <label for="location">Location</label><br/>
            <select id="location" name="location">
                <?php foreach ($getLocation->fetchAll() as $row) { ?>
                <option name="location" value="<?=$row["location_id"] ?>"><?=$row["location"] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select><p/>
            
            <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create"/>&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to insert those id values from location_id into product_location_id via a form  but it gives me errors when I try to execute my insert statement.

**the errors I receive:**

> Notice: Undefined index: product_location_id in D:\wamp\www\crudmetlogin2\src\Classes\Manager.php on line 23
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_location_id' cannot be null' in D:\wamp\www\crudmetlogin2\src\Classes\Manager.php on line 25
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_location_id' cannot be null in D:\wamp\www\crudmetlogin2\src\Classes\Manager.php on line 25

So what do I need to do in order to get this working?

Comment: Did you check `var_dump($_POST)`? There is no `$_POST["product_location_id"]` - it should be `$_POST["location"]`.. Or rename the `name` of your input field.

Comment: Paul Spiegel when i press the create button it shows the data gets filled and nothing is empty. tried with var_dump("location") but it gives me the same error except location is undefined now.

Comment: I will repeat myself: Did you check `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's in it?

Comment: Paul Spiegel yes and the data it contains is the data i want to have. however it doesnt want to insert it into the database

Comment: But the first error message (notice) tells a different story. The name of the `select` field is `location`!

Comment: IbrahimShendy just tried it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted was to rename `<select id="location" name="location">` to `<select id="location" name="product_location_id">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All error seems due this line of code

```
  $statement->bindValue(4, $_POST["product_location_id"]);
```

It seems product_location_id not exist in the form of your html,
I guess product_location_id should came here.

```
<select id="location" name="location">
                <?php foreach ($getLocation->fetchAll() as $row) { ?>
                <option name="location" value="<?=$row["location_id"] ?>"><?=$row["location"] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select><p/>
```

So try to change the name of select like this

```
<select id="location" name="product_location_id">
                <?php foreach ($getLocation->fetchAll() as $row) { ?>
                <option name="location" value="<?=$row["location_id"] ?>"><?=$row["location"] ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select><p/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form has a dropdown called `location`

```
<select id="location" name="location">
```

But your PHP Script is calling it `product_location_id`

```
$statement->bindValue(4, $_POST["product_location_id"]);
```

So change code to

```
$statement->bindValue(4, $_POST["location"]);
```

> Note `<option>` tags dont have a `name` attribute so remove it from this line

```
<option name="location" value="<?=$row["location_id"] ?>"><?=$row["location"] ?></option>
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ get rid of this
```